# Match entire columns between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a two dataframes

```
y <- data.frame(y1=seq(1:5), y2=letters[seq(1:5)])
x <- data.frame(x1=seq(1:5)*3,x2=seq(1:5), x3=letters[5:9], x4=letters[1:5])
```

and I wat to extract those columns from

> x

that entirely match

> y

columns.

Does someone have any clue?

Thank you

Comment: This: `x[x %in% y]` No wait, what do you mean but completely match? which column with which?

Comment: I tried this but the output has 3 columns instead of 2.

Comment: so you want `y`? But you want to get it as a subset of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop and do a comparison

```
x[sapply(y, function(.y) which(colSums(x== as.character(.y))== nrow(y)))]
```

---

Or another option is

```
i1 <- sapply(x, paste, collapse=",") %in% sapply(y, paste, collapse=",")
i1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
x[i1]
```

Comment: `x <- data.frame(x1=seq(1:5)*3,x2=seq(1:5)*2, x3=letters[5:9], x4=letters[1:5])` it does not work for this.

Comment: @Masoud Second solution should work for the new example

Comment: @akrun what if instead of letters we have all numeric values?

Comment: @JohnnyFactolive  By using the `paste` option, it should get the expeced output.  But, you may have to check for float/double where the precision comes into picture

Comment: @akrun Thank you again! ;)